# Using geocoding in asp.net mvc and want to transfer latitude and longitude from JS to some function in controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

UPDATED.

I tried what you said. The function is.

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult populate_place(string lati, string longi)
   {
  list_placesModels list_place = new list_placesModels();
  list_place.Latitude = lati;
  list_place.Longitude = longi;
  return View();
   }
```

But know its is not showing the new view. I don't know why ? Still the old view is shown. It is not redirecting to new view.
The new view is not shown. It still remains on the same view.

////////////

I am using Geo-coding feature of Google maps to access latitude and longitude of a location in my Razor view in asp.net mvc application.

I want to pass that Latitude and longitude to a function in controller. But nothing is happening. Below is my code snippet.

JS code:

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker( {
    map: map,
    [0].geometry.location
  });

  // I want to pass these value of latitude and longitude a function 
  // list_places() in UserController.
  latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
  longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();   

  $.post("/User/list_places",
    {
      lati: latitude,
      longi : longitude
     });
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult list_places(string usernameid, string lati, string longi) {

  list_placesModels list_place = new list_placesModels();
  list_place.Latitude = lati;
  list_place.Longitude = longi;
  return View(list_place);
}
```

Comment: I assume you have a view called 'populate_place'? Maybe try RedirectToAction() instead?

Comment: i tried that. but that is also not working. Don't know why the view is stuck. I tried even Redirecting it to other view as well as function. While debugging all those function are called by the view is not changed.

Comment: Right ok, at lunch I'm going to try and get an example working myself. What version of mvc are you using?

Comment: I am using MVC 3. And basically i am working on windows Azure application. I don't mind sharing my code if you want to see what's wrong with the code.

Comment: That might be easier.

Comment: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=2baa4bdfd79cfab0&id=2BAA4BDFD79CFAB0%21105                                            i have shared the code relevant for this question here

Comment: I've got it working on my machine, I've updated my answer to represent the working solution.

Comment: I have an answer for your related question also, but well get this one sorted first i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a few things are missing, firstly a [HttpPost] attribute on the action you are posting too, then the correct number of arguments, it look slike your passing in 2 but expecting 3? See below for a working example.

**Html/Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function buttonclick() {
    var requestData = {
        lati: 'latitude',
        longi: 'longitude'
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/populate_place',
        type: 'POST',
        data: requestData,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
};
</script>

<button onclick="buttonclick()">Click</button>
```

**Controller Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult populate_place(string lati, string longi)
{
    return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
}
```

If you put a breakpoint on the controller actions return if you inspect the parameters you'll see they are populated.

Comment: I changed action to take a single string but still while debugging it is not hit.                                                           Actually (http://incredibleindiaapp.cloudapp.net/User/list_places?usernameid=anurag) if you open this link. When a user search about some place and press find button than latitude and longitude are displayed. I want to display those latitude and longitude in the 2 boxes (Latitude and longitude boxes)

Comment: Your controller action isnt set to accept Post requests, if you add a [HttpPost] attribute to it that might help. Also try being more specific around the ajax request (see updated answer). This is all off the top of my head so you might need to tweak the code a little.

Comment: Adding [HttpPost] solve this problem and there is no need of single string argument. passing three string will also work. But i can't add [HttpPost] because i am also calling the same function(list_places) somewhere else and adding [HttpPost] gives error. So is there any other way so that i dont have to add [HttpPost] ?

Comment: Not without changing loads of other stuff. But as it counts as a different signature you can have 2 actions, 1 with the HttpPost and one without. If you want to avoid duplicating code you could pull the content of the controller into a private method that both 'overloads' could utilize?

Comment: actually i am trying the same thing as you told. will let you know ASAP whether it works. currently getting error when calling view.     BTW thanks a lot :)

Comment: Let me know how U get on, I must be forgetting something as I've done it before :S

Comment: I tried the code you suggested. The values of latitude and longitude are passed but even after "return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");" the view remains the same. Still old view is shown. It is not redirecting to new view. Even About function in Home controller is called but view is not changing.

Comment: Right ok, so thats this question answered i guess, Can you mark mine as answer and we'll work on your next issue in the other question?

Comment: Would you mind clicking the tick that should be displayed next to the up/down vote arrows to mark as answer, i see you upvoted it (much appreciated) but a tick will mean others with the same issue might find it easier. Plus I'll get more points, and points make prizes! lol. Check your other question on redirecting to a new page, I've made a starting point for a conversation about it.

Comment: I want to stick with using ajax for transferred data. Data is transferred as i already mentioned but view is not changing ??